# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: Unexpected character

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are getting the below error message when trying to read content that has href tag and results in bad request.

> 15:08:57.712 [ajp-nio-9014-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.c.a.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/u01/websites/gbk/WEB-INF/lib/dxa-data-model-2.0.0.jar!/com/sdl/dxa/api/datamodel/model/util/ListWrapper$RichTextDataListWrapper.class]
>   15:08:57.746 [ajp-nio-9014-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
>   15:08:59.668 [ajp-nio-9014-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://10.40.6.23:8998/ModelService/PageModel/tcm/27//en/about-us/contact-us?includes=INCLUDE" resulted in 200 (null)
>   15:08:59.670 [ajp-nio-9014-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading [class com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.PageModelData] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@61a760aa]
>   15:08:59.707 [ajp-nio-9014-exec-1] DEBUG c.s.d.a.d.j.ModelDataTypeIdResolver - Found id = List`1 which we don't know, create a content holder to just save the data
>   15:08:59.713 [ajp-nio-9014-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.controller.GenericPageController.handleGetPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4049]
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4024] (through reference chain: com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.PageModelData["Regions"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.RegionModelData["Entities"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.EntityModelData["Content"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4049]
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4024] (through reference chain: com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.PageModelData["Regions"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.RegionModelData["Entities"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.EntityModelData["Content"])
>   15:08:59.714 [ajp-nio-9014-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.sdl.dxa.modules.generic.controller.GenericPageController.handleGetPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4049]
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4024] (through reference chain: com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.PageModelData["Regions"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.RegionModelData["Entities"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.EntityModelData["Content"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4049]
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4024] (through reference chain: com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.PageModelData["Regions"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.RegionModelData["Entities"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.EntityModelData["Content"])

One of the components' preview looks like this

```
"fullContent": {
      "$type": "ContentModelData",
      "paraContent": {
        "$type": "List`1",
        "$values": [
          {
            "Fragments": [
              "Email us<span><a href=\"mailto:clientg@address.com\" target=\"_blank\">clientg@address.com</a></span>"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fragments": [
              "Telephone<span><a href=\"tel:+0123456789\">+01234567890</a></span>"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Fragments": [
              "Mailing Address<span>Address Line 1,P.O. Box, Queens 12, Kuwait</span>"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: How does the Page’s JSON look (if you preview the Page in the CME)? In particular the Rich Text field?

Comment: @RickPannekoek I have added the RichTextFields

Answer (score 2):

OK, the JSON fragment reveals the problem: the ``` "$type": "List``1" ``` is not expected (it should be `"$type": "RichTextData[]"`); you can see that in the exception message: "ModelDataTypeIdResolver - Found id = List`1 which we don't know".

This is an issue in the DXA 2.0 TBBs, which seems to have been fixed in code already: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/commit/a2c209d63a0685e74d2015fa83d8b30d1befc64c

This is a kind of hotfix on the DXA 2.0 TBBs, but a DXA 2.0.1 hotfix release has not been created, so you will have to build the TBBs yourself from code to get this fixed.  Alternatively, you can contact SDL Support to see if you can get this hotfix.

Comment: @rick is the hotfix you mentioned same as *R2DataModelCandidateFix.zip* provided to us recently by SDL support for case ID: 00353092?

Comment: @rick is the hotfix you mentioned same as *R2DataModelCandidateFix.zip* provided to us recently by SDL support for case ID: 00353092?

Comment: @Husain - I’m not sure (not that close to the fire anymore), but it seems a candidate hotfix has indeed been provided to a customer.

Comment: Hmmm, after inspecting the mentioned code change more carefully, I’m wondering if this defective behavior is actually caused rather than fixed by that code change.

Comment: @RickPannekoek thanks for confirming. I also had similar thoughts.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue occurs when you build the code tagged with 'DXA_2.0.1_Hotfix'